# Heap corruption by realloc when shrinking

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, valgrind, realloc

I am supposed to be building a database that "deletes" an element from a dynamically allocated array by moving it to the end of the array. When a block of that kind of elements gets large enough, the memory is supposed to be re-allocated to shrink the array and delete those useless elements for good.
THE ERROR:
Realloc is throwing:
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted

STEPS TO REPRODUCE THE ERROR (simplified) :
Choose from the interface the delete option.

THE CODE (simplified) :

in main():

```
 printf("\nEnter id to delete:");
                    scanf("%d",&idtoDelete);
                    delete(&log,idtoDelete);
```

in functions.c:

```
int delete(petCatalog *log, int idtoDelete) {
    //search to find which log has the id to delete.
    pet temp;
    int distance = 0;//between size and the pet to be deleted (temp) dld idtoDelete.
    int calibration = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;//virginslots from size-1 to thee first that awaits to be deleted dld virgin slots
    for (i = 0; i < log->size; i++) {
        if (log->array[i].id == idtoDelete) {            
            //move toDelete to my temp
            deepcopy_pet(&temp, &log->array[i], YES);
            log->virginSlots = log->size - i;
            //crerate a gap and fill the gap by overwriting
            distance = log->size - idtoDelete;
            calibration = distance + idtoDelete;
            for (j = i + 1; j < calibration; j++) {
                deepcopy_pet(&log->array[j - 1], &log->array[j], NO);                
            }
            log->size--;
            //temp to cap 
            deepcopy_pet(&log->array[log->cap], &temp, YES);        
            log->awaitDelete++; //all good till here
            log->virginSlots = log->cap - log->awaitDelete - log->size;
            if (log->virginSlots <= DOWNLIM) {
                log->cap = log->cap - log->awaitDelete;//meaning dump everything after: size+virginslots
                log->array = realloc(log->array, log->cap * sizeof(pet));
                if (log->array == NULL) {
                    printf("deletion failed to realloc");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            } else if (log->virginSlots >= UPLIM) {
                log->array = realloc(log->array, sizeof(pet) * (log->size) + DEFAULTVIRGIN);
                if (log->array == NULL) {
                    printf("\nfailed to realloc cause of UPLIM");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                log->cap = log->size + DEFAULTVIRGIN;
            }
        }
        //sort the array by breed again
    }
    return 0;
}

int deepcopy_pet(pet *dest, pet *source, int mallocDest) {          
    if (mallocDest == YES) {
        dest->sex = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * STRLIM);
        if (dest->sex == NULL) {
            printf("failed to malloc dest->breed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }     
       
        dest->breed = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * STRLIM);
        if (dest->breed == NULL) {
            printf("failed to malloc dest->breed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        dest->pet_age = (age*)malloc(sizeof(age));
        if (dest->pet_age == NULL) {
            printf("failed to malloc dest->breed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    dest->id = source->id;
    strcpy(dest->sex, source->sex);
    strcpy(dest->breed, source->breed);
    dest->pet_age->years = source->pet_age->years;
    dest->pet_age->months = source->pet_age->months;
    return 0;
}
```

and the description of the structs at head.h:

```
typedef struct age { 
    int years, months;
} age;

typedef struct pet {
    int id;
    char *sex;
    char *breed;
    age *pet_age;
} pet;

typedef struct petCatalog {
    pet *array;
    int size;//how many of them i got
    int cap;//how big is the array 
    //cap-count = empty_cells;
    int awaitDelete;
    int virginSlots;
} petCatalog;
```

Valgrind output (simplified):

```
==1260== Invalid write of size 8
==1260==    at 0x109621: deepcopy_pet (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x1094A9: delete (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x10A507: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==  Address 0x4a47108 is 8 bytes after a block of size 192 alloc'd
==1260==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1260==    by 0x10A3D2: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260== 
==1260== Invalid read of size 8
==1260==    at 0x109629: deepcopy_pet (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x1094A9: delete (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x10A507: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==  Address 0x4a47108 is 8 bytes after a block of size 192 alloc'd
==1260==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1260==    by 0x10A3D2: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260== 
==1260== Invalid write of size 8
==1260==    at 0x10965E: deepcopy_pet (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x1094A9: delete (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x10A507: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==  Address 0x4a47110 is 16 bytes after a block of size 192 alloc'd
==1260==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1260==    by 0x10A3D2: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260== 
==1260== Invalid read of size 8
==1260==    at 0x109666: deepcopy_pet (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x1094A9: delete (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x10A507: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==  Address 0x4a47110 is 16 bytes after a block of size 192 alloc'd
==1260==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1260==    by 0x10A3D2: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260== 
==1260== Invalid write of size 8
==1260==    at 0x10969B: deepcopy_pet (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x1094A9: delete (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==    by 0x10A507: main (in /mnt/c/Users/georg/Desktop/projects/strays/a.out)
==1260==  Address 0x4a47118 is 24 bytes after a block of size 192 in arena "client"
==1260== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:305 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
```

I don't really get it, why am I supposed to be writing illegally 8 bytes in every malloc of the
deepcopy_pet() function, and reading 8 bytes upon every assignment to one of those variables
I have just malloced?

My question is formed that way, considering the quote:
"Heap errors have their origins at previous memory allocations but often occur after a bunch of those...".

Any suggestions?Thank you.

Full source code is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/gtsompanoglou/strays).

P.S. Also, a memo to help you (if you want) understand the algorithm of deletion in respetc to the variable names.Neither way,it's optional because I want to you to focus on the heap corruption explanation.

[image: The memo]

Comment: If you compile with debug information e.g. `gcc -g`, valgrind will tell you the line numbers of the faulty accesses, you should probably fix those first. The line numbers should help you decipher which specific access that was and what might be wrong with it.

Comment: If you want more help here, make a [mre], include it in the question. "Full source available on request" is not a recipe for a question that would help someone several years from now.

Comment: @dratenik, fair enough,repo is now public. All you need to do is clone it,compile main.c , choose 1 to enter a log, and 2 to delete it, you will see what going on right away.

Comment: @BlueDiary9  , I remember you helped me once, can you do it again ?

Comment: @kjohri , please can you make something out of this one too ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too complicated: why do you bother keeping the `pet` structure at the end of the array? Just free the allocated fields, copy the elements in place, and possibly reallocate the array if below a certain threshold. Deep copying is overkill here. Using an allocated structure for the `age` seems unnecessary as well and allocating `STRLIM` bytes for the strings seems both wasteful and unsafe as you do not check that the original string lengths are at most `STRLIM-1`. You should use `strdup()` instead.

Here is a simplified version:

```
int delete(petCatalog *log, int idtoDelete) {
    //search to find which log has the id to delete.
    for (int i = 0; i < log->size; i++) {
        if (log->array[i].id == idtoDelete) {
            // free the element data
            free(log->array[i].sex);
            free(log->array[i].breed);
            free(log->array[i].pet_age);
            // copy the remaining elements over the deleted entry
            memmove(&log->array[i], &log->array[i + 1], (log->size - i - 1) * sizeof(log->array[i]));
            log->size--;
            if (log->cap - log->size >= DOWNLIM) {
                // shrink the array, cannot fail.
                int new_cap = log->size + 2; // what ever you shrink it to.
                pet *new_array = realloc(log->array, new_cap * sizeof(log->array[0]));
                if (new_array != NULL) {
                    log->array = new_array;
                    log->cap = new_cap;
                }
            }
            // no need to sort after deleting an element
            return 1;  // element was deleted
        }
    }
    return 0;  // element was not found
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you interest. Note that I dont want to free those pointers because I am going to have to malloc them again.I want the element to be able to be overwritten at any time and thus remain functional. My code is not complicated, my algorithm is difficult to understand if you dont pay enough attention. Also I have to use those types of structs because I was instructed so.

Comment: Sorry for insisting: you clone the structures using `deepcopy_pet` many times, causing much overhead and memory leaks, just to avoid reallocating the single element you delete? This is overkill and incorrect. If you want to make fewer calls to `malloc()`, make `sex` and `breed` char arrays instead of pointers and `age` an inline structure and there will be no need to allocate or free anything when deleting an entry.

Comment: The code is too long and too complicated. After re-formating it re-reading, the bug seems to be here: `deepcopy_pet(&log->array[log->cap], &temp, YES);` which stores the deleted element beyond the end of the allocated array. Note that you never free the memory allocated for `temp`, causing memory leaks.  I strongly suggest you simplify the design and concentrate on getting the full program to work correctly first. Use `valgrind` to check for memory leaks and corruption.

Comment: I followed your advice and replaced deepcopy_pet() (that was leaking memory) with memcpy. My problem is that I am still getting the same "invalid next size error" , but now my program works fine only in valgrind! How is that possible...

Comment: Do you use `memcpy` or `memmove`? If the source and destination objects overlap, you must use `memmove()`. You could also just write `temp = log->array[i];`.  The main problem in your code is you copy `temp` to `log->array[log->cap]`, which is incorrect.